# Not able to type in input field

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

Hi I write a small component

```
export default class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.state = { tags: [], value: "" };
  }
  onKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({ tags: [...this.state.tags, e.target.value], value: "" });
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div styleName="fieldset width-95">
          <label>Tags</label>
          <div>
            <div>
              {this.state.tags.map(tag => (
                <span>{tag}</span>
              ))}
            </div>
            <input
              type="text"
              onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
              value={this.state.value}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

after writing 1st time when I enter.it creates a tag but after that, I can't type anything in the input field. can anyone please explain how to enable typing so that I will be able to create another tag.

Comment: Hi Ritesh, please see my solution below and let me know if that helps :)

Comment: @ChristopherNgo yes it works .thanks.i accepted as answer

Comment: Awesome! Happy coding :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You also need an `onChange` handler as well to update `state` on user-input. Otherwise `this.state.value` will never update.

```
class TextInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
    this.state = { tags: [], value: "" };
  }
  onKeyPress(e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({ tags: [...this.state.tags, e.target.value], value: "" });
    }
  }

  handleOnChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      value: e.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div styleName="fieldset width-95">
          <label>Tags</label>
          <div>
            <div>
              {this.state.tags.map(tag => (
                <span>{tag}</span>
              ))}
            </div>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.handleOnChange}
              onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
              value={this.state.value}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

See working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-https-t02h2

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you forgot to add an `onClick` event for the `input`, this will handle when you type something in it (You only need to update the state every time the `onChange` event is fire), like this (I've also made an update to a more ES6 syntax):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class TextInput extends Component {
  state = { tags: [], value: "" };

  onKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
      this.setState({ tags: [...this.state.tags, e.target.value], value: "" });
    }
  };

  onClick = e => {
    if (e && e.target && e.target.value) {
      this.setState({ value: e.target.value });
    }
  };

  render() {
    const { tags, value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <div styleName="fieldset width-95">
          <label>Tags</label>
          <div>
            <div>
              {tags.map(tag => (
                <span>{tag}</span>
              ))}
            </div>
            <input
              type="text"
              onChange={this.onClick}
              onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
              value={value}
            />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.And you remove value which you are set on state.And use onChange method.

```
      import React, { Component } from 'react';

    export default class TextInput extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.onKeyPress = this.onKeyPress.bind(this);
      this.state = { tags: [] };
     }
     onKeyPress(e) {
      if (e.key === "Enter") {
        this.setState({ tags: [...this.state.tags, e.target.value], value: 
        e.target.value });
        console.log("tag:",this.state.tags)
      }
    }

    handleInputChange = (event) => {
        this.setState({ [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
      };

    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <div styleName="fieldset width-95">
            <label>Tags</label>
            <div>
              <div>
                {this.state.tags.map(tag => (
                  <span >{tag}</span>
                ))}
              </div>
              <input
                type="text"
                onKeyPress={this.onKeyPress}
                name="demo"
                value={this.state.value}
                onChange={this.handleInputChange}
              />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
       );
     }
    }
```